# php function call default args

Tags: php, function, args

How to I make a call to a function where I want to use some default args and some some I pass in:

```
function genericlist (array $arr, string $name, [string $attribs = null], 
           [string $key = 'value'], [string $text = 'text'], 
           [mixed $selected = NULL], [ $idtag = false], [ $translate = false])
```

I only want to pass in $arr, $name, $selected and use the default values for everything else, how do I do that? I know I could pass in the default values and go in order but I there must me another way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, either you do pass the default values indeed, either you reorder the arguments so as to put $selected before all other optional arguments.

Also, you can request for named parameters on PHP development forums.

Comment: Yea I think I am getting php mixed up with some other language. I am probably not going to request this feature in the PHP development forums....

Comment: I knew about the pass in the default values and that is what I ended up doing so I am marking your response as the correct one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) might be able to give you a solution, if you're interested in using the arrays route:

```
function func1($args = array())
{
   $defaults = array('X' => 10, 'Y' => 30);
   $args = array_merge($defaults, $args);
   // $args now has default arguments and user supplied arguments

   return $args;
}

func1(); // array('X' => 10, 'Y' => 30)
func1(array('X' => 40)); // array('X' => 40, 'Y' => 30)
```

Comment: This probably works but it more complicated than I need. I thought there was a better way but I think I am getting php mixed up with javascript or something. Anyways I am just going type in the defaults as arguments. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions:

1. Create the function with null arguments. When a null value is supplied, check for it within the function and replace it with a default. This is round-about in that it's no longer specified in the prototype, but does offer the default value solution with minimal effort.
2. Turn your prototype in to an array argument with key-value pairs. This is similar to the first solution, but you can use a method such as [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to combine the "default value" array and the newly passed argument values.

Example 1:

```
function abc($foo = null, $bar = null)
{
  // defaulting parameters
  if (is_null($foo)) $foo = 'Hello, world!'; // foo default value
  if (is_null($bar)) $bar = 123.45; // bar default value

  // on-ward with the function
}

// override bar, but not foo:
abc(null, 987.65);
```

Example 2:

```
function def($args)
{
  // defaulting parameters
  $args = array_merge(
    array(
      'foo' => 'Hello, world!', // Default foo value
      'bar' => 123.45           // default bar value
    ),
    $args // override with supplied values
  );

  // on-ward with the function
}

// override bar, but not foo
def(array('bar'=>987.65));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is more complicated than I need. I thought there was a better way but I think I am getting php mixed up with javascript or some other language. Anyways I am just going type in the defaults as arguments.